# Upvoted and accepted answers in the review pane

Tags: feature-request, review

Should these posts really be in the first answers pane in the review tab?

While I understand that they are technically the first answers that the user has posted, through upvotes and/or accepting it as an answer, they do not need to be reviewed automatically in the same way that the first posts of other users that have gone un-upvoted and un-accepted need to be.

In addition (and I do not know if this is the case currently) but perhaps all posts by users that have less than 10 rep that meet this criteria should be put in the review pane. It does not really matter if the post is his first or second if they are posted at basically the same time, and have not been upvoted.

As is, the first answer page is cluttered with many answers that have upvotes that really don't need the review.

Comment: First answer by a new user, with a single upvote and accepted, smells like a sockpuppet... And since most won't bother checking a question that has an accepted answer, it's up to the reviewers to take a closer look... Not to decide if it's a sockpuppet of course, but to see if the answer is any good.

Comment: One of the points of the review page is to encourage new users by up voting their quality content, so I don't see the problem here.

Comment: TimStone, if the content has already been upvoted, then that has already been accomplished. At the same time, there are so many posts that are still in the queue that these posts take attention away from the posts that need it more. Perhaps it should just be sortable by this or something. @YannisRizos, I disagree. It could be a sock puppet, but is likely not. While every post should be looked at, I don't think this type of post should be lumped in with the others.

Comment: @soandos Cool. So you won't catch _my_ sockpuppets... :P

Comment: @YannisRizos, I've only ever caught a few sock puppets, but those that I have caught have not been by using /review. Most of the posts that I review are more than a few months old. I don't think that they can really be caught using /review as you don't generally look at all of low rep users answers to see if they are a puppet. I do do that if I remember them posting about the same topic several times in a relatively short time period.

Comment: @soandos Well, there are 143 first answers (day) to review right now, so I see your point...